# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 stuck on login screen

Tags: login, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04

I switched from Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS  to Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 two weeks ago, and it was working fine. But for some reason, if I upgrade to 17.04, it gets stuck on the login screen. That is, after I click my user account and enter my password, it gets stuck on the grey screen. The mouse pointer doesn't move. And, I can't start a tty. But, I can lock the account by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1. But when I try unlocking it by entering my password, same problem again. This only happens on 17.04 for me. 16.10 works fine.

Comment: Almost exactly the same problem here, and no answers found.  Difference is that I installed Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  16.04 still runs fine, in fact the 17.04 GNOME Live CD ran fine until install.  Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz × 2 ... graphics = Gallium 0.4 on NV42 ... Dell XPS5

Comment: Same but Unity, can't even start logging in, happens only with 4.10 kernel. Using 4.8 for now.

Comment: my keyboard is not working as well any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with ubuntu 17.04 on a fresh install.
The issue was the graphical part (nvidia/intel on board), so on the login I :

- Switch to a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1
- Install nvidia driver and nvidia prime

  > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
  >   sudo apt-get update
  >   ubuntu-drivers devices
  >   sudo apt-get install nvidia-(number) nvidia-prime
- Switch from nvidia to intel in a terminal

  > sudo prime-select intel
  >   sudo prime-select nvidia

When using nvidia, it was ok!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I wasn't even able to use CTRL + ALT + F1/F3 to use a terminal only. So after many restarts I tricked it login to recovery mode from which I did yet another release upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. 17.10 does not have issue like this one and the GUI is smoooth as a butter!