# Dell XPS13 9360 stuck at login after update to Ubuntu 17.04 because keyboard and mouse don't work

Tags: keyboard, login, mouse, 17.04

I have a Dell XPS13 9360 and have been dualbooting 16.04 since last year. Now I wanted to upgrade to 17.04.

Everything went smooth, no hiccups at all until I reboot the system and see the login screen. Then my mouse won't work. And my keystrokes are not registered. So basically I can't log on since I can't type or move the mouse.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> does nothing since the keyboard is not responding. Well, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button is working.

So is there a fix for this or do I need to format the HDD and start over?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 stuck on login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906625/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-stuck-on-login-screen)

Comment: Take not when (date:hhmmss) your computer froze, so you can boot a live-cd and look in `/var/log/syslog` at your computer HD what line errors you got. If you can post it at your question, it are thankful.

Comment: @usmanayubsh: No, in that question OP could still issue key strokes.

Comment: You may need to use ctrl+alt+fn+f1.

Answer (score 2):

Get to the GRUB menu, and hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key (to edit). Using the arrow keys, find the line that contains "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset". Then hit <kbd>F10</kbd>. See if that allows your system to fully boot and allow you to login. You may be in low-graphics mode. If it does allow you to log in, then your video card drivers probably need to be reinstalled.